# Populate HTML table from Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I would like to take data from a Javascript array and place it into an HTML table. A Javascript file, including arrays and basic functions, was provided. I want to put the array data into my HTML table by calling the functions. The following Javascript was given:

```
var subject = ['Call Your Mother', 'Cheap Online Meds', 'Change Your Life Today', 'Sppoky Stories', 'Meet Singles In Your Area', 'Have You Heard?', 'Yo', 'RE: Looking for a three legged cat', 'Get Rich Quick!', 'FW: Token Chain Email'];
var sender = ['Mary Monster', 'Dave Danger', 'Spam Master', 'Spike Spurner', 'Ray Ranger', 'Catherine Chaos', 'Van Pire', 'Andy Argye', 'Rick Roger', 'Sue Mee'];
var body = ['Message 1','Message 2','Message 3','Message 4','Message 5','Message 6','Message 7','Message 8','Message 9','Message 10'];


function loadGeeMails(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var message = generateMessage();
        window.geemails.push(message);
    }
}

function generateMessage(date){
    var message = {};
    message.date = date || getRandomDate();
    message.subject = getRandomElement(subject);
    message.sender = getRandomElement(sender);
    message.body = getRandomElement(body);
    return message;
}

function getRandomElement(arr){
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

function getNewMessage(){
    var now = new Date();
    return generateMessage(now);
}

function getRandomDate(){
    var year = 2013;
    var month = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
    var day = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1;
    var hours = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
    var minutes = Math.floor(Math.random() * 59) + 1;
    return new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes);
}

//load intial GeeMail data to window object
(function(){
    window.geemails = [];
    loadGeeMails(); 
})();
```

I want to use those arrays and/or functions to populate the HTML table below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <Title>Kevin Gee-mail Challenge</title>
        <script src="js/mail-generator.js"></script>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script>
      window.onload = function(){
          //Call javascript here  
      };


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container" id="main"></div>
        <h1>This is your inbox.</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Sender</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Body</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="date"></td>
                <td class="sender"></td>
                <td class="subject"></td>
                <td class="body"></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And the problem/question is? Your table is missing a closing `<tr />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var subject = ['Call Your Mother', 'Cheap Online Meds', 'Change Your Life Today', 'Sppoky Stories', 'Meet Singles In Your Area', 'Have You Heard?', 'Yo', 'RE: Looking for a three legged cat', 'Get Rich Quick!', 'FW: Token Chain Email'];
var sender = ['Mary Monster', 'Dave Danger', 'Spam Master', 'Spike Spurner', 'Ray Ranger', 'Catherine Chaos', 'Van Pire', 'Andy Argye', 'Rick Roger', 'Sue Mee'];
var body = ['Message 1','Message 2','Message 3','Message 4','Message 5','Message 6','Message 7','Message 8','Message 9','Message 10'];


function loadGeeMails(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var message = generateMessage();
        window.geemails.push(message);
    }
}

function generateMessage(date){
    var message = {};
    message.date = (date || getRandomDate()).toDateString();
    message.subject = getRandomElement(subject);
    message.sender = getRandomElement(sender);
    message.body = getRandomElement(body);
    return message;
}

function getRandomElement(arr){
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

function getNewMessage(){
    var now = new Date();
    return generateMessage(now);
}

function getRandomDate(){
    var year = 2013;
    var month = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
    var day = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1;
    var hours = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
    var minutes = Math.floor(Math.random() * 59) + 1;
    return new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes);
}

$("document").ready(function(){
 window.geemails = [];
    loadGeeMails(); console.log(window.geemails);
      $("#emailTemplate").tmpl(window.geemails).appendTo("#emailContainer");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
<body>

        <div class="container" id="main"></div>
        <h1>This is your inbox.</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Sender</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Body</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody id="emailContainer">                
            </tbody>    
        </table>
    
    <!-- This is the template -->
<script id="emailTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
                    <td> ${date} </td>
                    <td> ${sender} </td>
                    <td> ${subject} </td>
                    <td> ${body} </td>
                </tr>
</script>
```

Here is the better way of doing it just use the JQuery template bindings and this could be real easy and clean.Please find the JSfiddle [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cc44s778/)

```
JS Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/cc44s778/
```

Comment: Jon P --  i have people saying to add link in the answer. Now you are saying code in the answer. What should i follow.

Comment: Always have code in the answer or question, a fiddle in addition to code is good. Using StackOverflows code snippet (the <> button in the editor) is better.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Is it fine now.Keeping this way ?. Please mark my response

Comment: Thanks for the answer, HG-1221. Based on the result pane in JSFiddle that is indeed what I wanted to produce. For reasons of ineptitude I've been unable to get the code to work for me, but I'm trying to reverse engineer the ideas you used. Thanks and mahalo.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that will iterate over `window.geemails` and create `tr` elements which will append to the table in question. For example :-

```
function createTableRows(){
    for(var i=0; i < window.geemails.length; i++){
        var obj = window.geemails[i];
        var trElm = document.createElement('tr');

        var dateTdElm = document.createElement('td');
        var dateTxt = document.createTextNode(obj.date);
        dateTdElm.appendChild(dateTxt);

        var senderTdElm = document.createElement('td');
        var senderTxt = document.createTextNode(obj.sender);
        senderTdElm.appendChild(senderTxt);

        var subjectTdElm = document.createElement('td');
        var subjectTxt = document.createTextNode(obj.subject);
        subjectTdElm.appendChild(subjectTxt);

        var bodyTdElm = document.createElement('td');
        var bodyTxt = document.createTextNode(obj.body);
        bodyTdElm.appendChild(bodyTxt);

        trElm.appendChild(dateTdElm); 
        trElm.appendChild(senderTdElm);
        trElm.appendChild(subjectTdElm);
        trElm.appendChild(bodyTdElm);

        document.tables[0].appendChild(trElm);
    }
}
```

However, I would suggest using [datatables](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html) or a js library (if possible) for such requirements.
- good luck

Comment: Note that the DOM is recalculated for each manipulation of it. It is more efficient to only update the DOM once if possible.

Comment: As addition to @JonP comment you could use a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) as buffer and add the created rows in one go to DOM [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hq5e1cka/).