# From Javascript arrays to an HTML table (Arquero? Tidy.js? Data-Forge?)

Tags: javascript, html, arquero

Possibly a stupid question here. I have some tabular data (can be from a .csv file, but not necessarily) that I would like to output on a webpage. Ideally, I also want to preprocess that data and do some aggregation first.

Say, on my *index.html* file I have the following tag:

```
<table id="data"></table>
```

While my *script.js* file looks like this:

```
let my_data = {
   "Fruit": ["apple","peach","banana"],
   "Price": [2,3,2]
}
```

I thought that populating the html table with that data would be as simple as:

```
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = my_data
```

But it's obviously more complicated than that, according to some [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509690/populate-html-table-from-javascript-array) that I could find.

Where things get trickier, is that the tabular data on the *script.js* side will vary in its number of rows and columns, as I intend to do some data preprocessing.

I have considered the following libraries to help me with that:

- [Arquero.js](https://github.com/uwdata/arquero)
- [Tidy.js](https://pbeshai.github.io/tidy/)
- [Data-Forge](https://github.com/data-forge/data-forge-ts)

For instance, *Arquero* features a `.toHTML()` method, and I thought that I would just have to create a pair of `<div></div>` blocks and throw the *Arquero* table between them. But nope, won't work.

1. I'm considering using [Plotly's table](https://plotly.com/javascript/table/) for that, but **I'm wondering if there's an easy way to populate an HTML table with some data from my *.js* script**, bearing in mind that this data will not necessarily have the same shape (which means I can prepopulate the table on the HTML side).
2. **Is it possible to output an *Arquero / Tidy.js / Data-Forge* table object into an HTML element**, like div or figure, etc..?

I hope it makes sense :)

Thanks!

Comment: Use dataTables to convert from JSON array to HTML table: https://datatables.net/

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I didn't know about this, and will investe a bit of time on it then! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- (A) ALL WE NEED IS A <DIV> CONTAINER -->
<div id="data"></div>
 
<script>
// (B) DUMMY ARRAY
var my_data = ["doge", "cate", "birb", "doggo", "moon moon", "awkward seal"];

// (C) CREATE HTML TABLE
// (C1) HTML TABLE ELEMENT
var myTable = document.createElement("table"),
    row = myTable.insertRow(), cell;

// (C2) LOOP THROUGH ARRAY & GENERATE ROWS-CELLS
var perrow = 2; // 2 CELLS PER ROW
my_data.forEach((value, i) => {
  // ADD CELL
  cell = row.insertCell();
  cell.innerHTML = value;
 
  // CLICK ON CELL TO DO SOMETHING
  // cell.onclick = FUNCTION;
 
  // TO PASS IN A RUNNING NUMBER OR PARAMETER
  // cell.onclick = () => { console.log(i); };
 
  // BREAK INTO NEXT ROW
  var next = i + 1;
  if (next%perrow==0 && next!=my_data.length) { row = myTable.insertRow(); }
});

// (D) ATTACH TABLE TO CONTAINER
document.getElementById("data").appendChild(myTable);
```

Comment: This is really great, thank you very much for your help, this is super detailed and easy to follow :)